# Pagination pure javaScript error Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am trying create a pagination buti am reciving this error

scripts.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefinedhideItems @ scripts.js:30(anonymous function) @ scripts.js:43+

I dont know what is the problem the functions hideItems and showItems individualy works but give the error but whe i call changePage only works the hideItems function given the error.

```js
// Global Variables
var itemsPerPage = 10;
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('student-list');
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('student-item');
var actualPage = 1;
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("student-item");
var index;


// Count the numbrer of items in the list
var getNumberOfItems = function () {
  var numbrerOfItems = items.length;
  return (numbrerOfItems);
}
// Generating rhe number of pages
var getNumberOfPages = function () {
  var numberOfPages = parseInt(getNumberOfItems() / itemsPerPage);
  if ( getNumberOfItems() % itemsPerPage > 0 ){
    numberOfPages += 1;
  }
  return numberOfPages;
}


var hideItems = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i <= getNumberOfItems(); i++) {
    items[i].style.display = "none";
    console.log(i);
  };
    
}

function showItemsByPage (page) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= itemsPerPage - 1; i++) {
    index = page * itemsPerPage - itemsPerPage  + i;
    items[index].style.display = "block";
    console.log(index);
  }; 
}

function changePage (number) {
  
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", hideItems());
  document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", showItemsByPage(number));
}

changePage(1);
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #e1f1f6;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

.page{
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.page-header{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
  .page-header h2{
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
  }

  .page-header .student-search{
    float: right;
  }

    .page-header .student-search input{
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .page-header .student-search button{
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: #4ba6c3;
      color: #fff
    }

.student-list{}

  .student-item{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  }

    .student-details{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
    }

      .student-details .avatar{
        width: 40px;
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 20px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 14px
      }

      .student-details h3{
        margin: 4px 0 2px 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #4ba6c3;
      }

      .student-details .email{
        color: #888;
        font-size: 14px;
      }


    .joined-details{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      text-align: right;
    }

      .joined-details .date{
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #999;
      }

  .student-item:last-child{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

.pagination{
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
 
  .pagination li{
    display: inline;
  }

    .pagination li a{
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 3px 8px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #4ba6c3;
    }

    .pagination li a.active,
    .pagination li a:hover{
      background-color: #4ba6c3;
      color: #fff;
    }
.hidenItems{
  display: none;
}
.showItems{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Students</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2>Students</h2>
      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>aapo niskanen</h3>
                <span class="email">aapo.niskanen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>phillip cox</h3>
                <span class="email">phillip.cox@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/38.jpg">
                <h3>zilda moreira</h3>
                <span class="email">zilda.moreira@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/23.jpg">
                <h3>lilou le gall</h3>
                <span class="email">lilou.le gall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/16/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/94.jpg">
                <h3>lucy hall</h3>
                <span class="email">lucy.hall@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/11/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>mark colin</h3>
                <span class="email">mark.colin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/14/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/14.jpg">
                <h3>sara alves</h3>
                <span class="email">sara.alves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/19/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>ramon macrae</h3>
                <span class="email">ramon.macrae@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/15.jpg">
                <h3>connor taylor</h3>
                <span class="email">connor.taylor@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/11.jpg">
                <h3>aymeric morel</h3>
                <span class="email">aymeric.morel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/49.jpg">
                <h3>lorenz otto</h3>
                <span class="email">lorenz.otto@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>karl williamson</h3>
                <span class="email">karl.williamson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/34.jpg">
                <h3>ouassim heering</h3>
                <span class="email">ouassim.heering@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>roberto molina</h3>
                <span class="email">roberto.molina@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/28.jpg">
                <h3>jordan hubert</h3>
                <span class="email">jordan.hubert@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/13/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/29.jpg">
                <h3>melvin baker</h3>
                <span class="email">melvin.baker@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/18/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/26.jpg">
                <h3>everett gordon</h3>
                <span class="email">everett.gordon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/82.jpg">
                <h3>aiden ma</h3>
                <span class="email">aiden.ma@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/62.jpg">
                <h3>florent gerard</h3>
                <span class="email">florent.gerard@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/12/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/96.jpg">
                <h3>amber chen</h3>
                <span class="email">amber.chen@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/9.jpg">
                <h3>alexandra davies</h3>
                <span class="email">alexandra.davies@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/11/13</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/57.jpg">
                <h3>sergio cole</h3>
                <span class="email">sergio.cole@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/98.jpg">
                <h3>edgar dixon</h3>
                <span class="email">edgar.dixon@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/17/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/94.jpg">
                <h3>kirk myers</h3>
                <span class="email">kirk.myers@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/17/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/28.jpg">
                <h3>ani hesseling</h3>
                <span class="email">ani.hesseling@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 08/14/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/24.jpg">
                <h3>victoire bonnet</h3>
                <span class="email">victoire.bonnet@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/13/16</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/44.jpg">
                <h3>marcos morales</h3>
                <span class="email">marcos.morales@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/12/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/75.jpg">
                <h3>nils neumann</h3>
                <span class="email">nils.neumann@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/86.jpg">
                <h3>emily harrison</h3>
                <span class="email">emily.harrison@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>matthew fortin</h3>
                <span class="email">matthew.fortin@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 03/18/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/32.jpg">
                <h3>charlotte steward</h3>
                <span class="email">charlotte.steward@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 02/18/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>marceau rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">marceau.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/13/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>hudson anderson</h3>
                <span class="email">hudson.anderson@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/33.jpg">
                <h3>warren phillips</h3>
                <span class="email">warren.phillips@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>leo niva</h3>
                <span class="email">leo.niva@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/14/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/3.jpg">
                <h3>hani prevoo</h3>
                <span class="email">hani.prevoo@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 01/11/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/79.jpg">
                <h3>veronica rodriguez</h3>
                <span class="email">veronica.rodriguez@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/17/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/41.jpg">
                <h3>ginestal das neves</h3>
                <span class="email">ginestal.das neves@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/19/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/63.jpg">
                <h3>devon barnes</h3>
                <span class="email">devon.barnes@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/19/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/55.jpg">
                <h3>brennan pierce</h3>
                <span class="email">brennan.pierce@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/15/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>zachary singh</h3>
                <span class="email">zachary.singh@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/19/11</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/35.jpg">
                <h3>arlo harris</h3>
                <span class="email">arlo.harris@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/60.jpg">
                <h3>hannah ginnish</h3>
                <span class="email">hannah.ginnish@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 05/17/14</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/95.jpg">
                <h3>goos brunt</h3>
                <span class="email">goos.brunt@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 09/15/12</span>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/91.jpg">
                <h3>eduard riedel</h3>
                <span class="email">eduard.riedel@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 06/12/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="pagination">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="active" href="#" value="1" onclick = "changePage(1)">1</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#" onclick = "changePage(2)">2</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#" onclick = "changePage(3)">3</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#" onclick = "changePage(4)">4</a>
          </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#" onclick = "changePage(5)">5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src= "js/scripts.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey David, did you see my answer? Did it help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a typical "Off by one" error.

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i <= getNumberOfItems(); i++)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < getNumberOfItems(); i++)
```

Comment: Thaks that was the solution can you explain me, please

Comment: Glad I could help you out, I will add some explanation as soon as I can